# Use of input() statement

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am new to Python and Visual Studio Code. When I try to use the input() statement and run the code, the terminal window shows the prompt which I have included in the statement but does not show a curser after the prompt where the user should type in the input. I need to mouse click in the terminal window after the prompt and then press enter for the input to be accepted. This doesn't seem right. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't seem right ? The `input` can read text, it doesn't trigger the console to get the mouse cursor

Comment: why should the debugger move focus to the terminal, use Ctrl+BackTick

Answer (score 0):

If you run a python script in an IDE, it will fire up an integrated terminal and will execute the program by doing something like `python <your_file_name>.py`.

This process isn't supposed to change the IDE's focus to the terminal. Because often times, developers like to have their editor in focus even though their program is running in the terminal. And hence VSCode is developed to behave this way. You can see this exact behaviour in many modern IDEs.